# How to deal with modern Indian people's first names and surnames when declining in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit, names, declension

I have a question about how to deal with people's names when using Sanskrit in a modern context.

Let's say I want to say "Ãnanda is in the forest", I can say वन आनन्दः. Ignoring any possible confusion about whether आनन्द here refers to a person's name or bliss, at least the treatment of आनन्दः is clear, i.e., आनन्द is converted to आनन्दः and is declined as the word which is already present in Sanskrit.

However, how do we deal with non-Sanskrit names and/or surnames in modern Indian names when declining them in Sanskrit. Are there any rules for this? Let's say I want to say (some made-up names) "Kavin Abraham" or "Imran Owaisi" or "Gajendra Shahane" + "is in the forest", how would one choose how to decline these names in Sanskrit?

Comment: The same ways as you deal with foreign names in other languages with nominal declension: leave them unchanged, add a suitable ending which then gets declined, or treat them as though they contained the ending.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer in terms of "the Sanskrit language", instead you would get an answer in terms of what some individual might do. There are some fluent second-language speakers, and you might pose the question to them. It could be interesting to see if they agree on an answer, or are there different opinions. One answer is "The question is meaningless, there is no such name in Sanskrit". Another explicitly follows the rules set down by Pāṇini; a third analogizes the target word to a similar existing Sanskrit word.